# NotifyItemRangeInserted Doesnt trigger Views to be Recycled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to initialize my list with a new one and im using notifyItemRangeInserted(0, List.size()). But this doesnt trigger the old views to be recycled. If i uses notifyDataset only then it does trigger it. The thing is that notifyDataset is very costly operation and i need another way.

Thank you

```
  public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable,CustomAdapter {

    private Context mCtx;
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private List<Pair<Integer,Object>> List;


    public Adapter(Context mCtx, EmployeeClickCallback, RecyclerView recycler,) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.recycler = recycler;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        Log.d("onViewRecycled","recycled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        }
    }

    public void setList(List<Pair<Integer,Object>> list){
        if(List!=null)
            List.clear();
        List= list;
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, List.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not creating the ViewHolder and also didn't implement onBindViewHolder. Also don't use first uppercase letter when you name your variables since it's against convention and can get mixed up with type `List`.

Comment: @TheKarlo95 This is just an example of the issue not the real code. Please answer the topic or delete your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should notify that the items were removed:

```
public void setList(List<Pair<Integer,Object>> list){
    if(mList != null) {
        final int size = mList.size();
        mList.clear();
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }
    mList.addAll(list);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(0, mList.size());
}
```